# Creating a UIbutton from an already defined Bezier Path?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uibezierpath

I have a range of defined Bezier Paths within one View Controller (the default). However specifically, I want to make one of them a UIButton (It doesn't have to lead anywhere yet but it would be great if it could print something on touch).

By looking at some similar questions, I have been able to define the Bezier Path I want and the UIButton separately on the simulator, but haven't been able to splice them together.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 350), radius: CGFloat(150), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

    //change the fill color
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    //you can change the stroke color
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    //you can change the line width
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 7.5

    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

  let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("Button tapped")
    }

}
```

How can I pass circlePath as a UIButton?.

Answer (score 0):

A UIButton is a UIView so you can add the layer you created to the button in just the same way as you did the view:

```
button.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Note that this layer will then cover the label of the UIButton, but an easy way to solve this is to change the z-position of the layer:

```
shapeLayer.zPosition = -1
```

E.g. if you want to add a circular layer to a button:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: button.bounds)
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
shapeLayer.zPosition = -1   
button.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Or, matching the circle in your example but creating the button before the shape:

```
// define circle parameters
let radius: CGFloat = 150
let center = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 350)

// create the button
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: center.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -radius, y: -radius)),
                                        size: CGSize(width: 2 * radius, height: 2 * radius)))

// create the circle layer
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: button.bounds)
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
shapeLayer.zPosition = -1

// add the circle layer to the button
button.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

view.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to switch around the position of the button and the path  to allow it to run. However, I'm only getting the 'button pressed' message whenever I tap on the position where the original button used to be, and not the circular layer. I'm trying to make the circular layer the only button on the view - sorry if I'm being unclear!

Comment: Yes, the frame of the button and that of the layer might be different. UIBezierPath(ovalIn: button.bounds) creates a path that, when assigned to the button, is inside the button. Do you have a particular reason why you want to declare a path first and then a button, and not the other way around?

Comment: It's has come out that way because I don't know so much. I'm more focused (probably unnecessarily) on the Path because I only want the stroke of the path to respond to touch, not the whole Circle. I'm also hoping to set up so that I can later apply an animated gradient to the stroke of the path

Comment: Ah, so you want a path that responds to touch? UIButton is really not suitable for that and that is probably what lead to the confusion. You should look for questions asking "How to detect touches on a CGPath" or create one yourself.

Comment: Exactly that - my bad for being vague. I'll do just that. Thanks Priebe